# Jave InputStream convert to Base64 String not able to open file

Tags: java

I am using an InputStream that is PDF file that needs to be able to converted to a Base64 string. The Base64 string is not correct format because when I decode the PDF file will not open. Is there a better way to do this?

```
PDFString =  fromStream(is);
String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(PDFString.getBytes());


public static String fromStream(InputStream in) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(line);
        out.append(newLine);
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

Comment: Your grammar is ill, but `java.util.Base64` offer `Base64.getDecoder().decode(byteArray)` and `Base64.getEncoder().encode(byteArray)`.

Comment: Why are you reading it in as a String?  Read in a byte stream, don't use Reader classes.

Comment: When I try to do import java.util.base64; the error I get is that it cant resolve the symbol base64?

Comment: In user code by convention, and in the standard library always, Java class names begin with an uppercase letter. Use `Base64` not `base64`. This is normally covered in the first page or two of any decent Java course or tutorial. And make sure you're using Java 8 (the only one currently supported); this particular library class didn't exist in earlier versions.